# Tailwindcss 3.0 heigh class is not working... not a clue

Tags: tailwind-css

Just trying to use h-40 class but not working

```
<div class="flex min-h-screen bg-cover max-w-screen-3xl" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Harlingen._Sint-Micha%C3%ABlkerk._Hoofdaltaar._HDR._12-07-2021._%28d.j.b%29_02.jpg);">
  <!-- wrapper App-->
  <div class="bg-slate-700/60 absolute flex flex-row inset-0 m-5 rounded-xl max-w-screen-2xl">
    <!-- Left menu section -->
    <div class="bg-zinc-800/90 p-5 w-16 rounded-tl-xl rounded-bl-xl"></div>
    <!-- Wrapper Main -->
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full overflow-auto">
      <!-- Top section -->
      <div class="bg-red-400/90 h-40 w-auto rounded-tr-xl p-5 sticky top-0"></div>
      <!-- wrapper body  -->
      <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
        <!-- body -->
        <div class="bg-green-400/90 border-2 w-full h-60 p-5"></div>
        <div class="bg-green-400/90 border-2 w-full h-96 p-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/gryfZM2drD

Comment: In the example you gave it seems like it's working. It's 10rem in height. I.e. 10 times the font size of the root element.

Comment: On which element are you trying to set it?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add class shrink-0 :-)